# Wrapped DIV in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, html

I have created an HTML page which works that has a wrapped div around div. However when I use the same HTML to process some XML through XSLT it places one div above another, can anyone think why it is doing this in XML/XSLT?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
               version="1.0"
               xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>


  <!-- Doctype - about:legacy-compat is XML equivalent of HTML5 doctype -->
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"
              omit-xml-declaration="yes"
              doctype-public="about:legacy-compat"
  />

  <xsl:template name="Document" match="/">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>BPD</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="big_picture_documentation_v3.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <div id="floated">
 <p>WRAP AROUND ME!</p>
</div>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Title" match="title">
  <h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </h1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="subheading" match="subheading">
  <h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </h2>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The CSS for formatting these divs can be seen below:

```
#container { margin: 5px;padding: 5px;border: 0px solid black;}
#floated { width: 227x;float: left;padding-right: 5px;padding-bottom: 10px;}
```

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="v3.xsl" ?>
 <document xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <data id="HowToUse" type="example" status="Complete">
   <content>
   <title>How To Navigate This Guide</title>
   <subheading>Using This Documentation</subheading>

    </content>
   </data>

</document>
```

Comment: what is the xml you are transforming?

Comment: i dont fully understand your problem here... it may be because there is a problem with the xslt and its attempting to output an empty node. to see if this is the problem add some random text after both  apply-templates parts between the header tags.

Comment: In the example the title will be outputted. For some reason, depending on where it is placed, the content is appearing directly below or above the floated div which it is meant to be wrapped around. However, the same straight HTML works as intended - Just not when it is being passed through XSLT

Comment: Perhaps this will clarify what I am trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/GLU4k/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <div id="container">
>  <div id="floated">
>  <p>WRAP AROUND ME!</p>
> </div>
> <xsl:apply-templates/>
> </div>
> ```

It seems to me that what you want is:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="floated">
  <p>WRAP AROUND ME!</p>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. In the end I rewrote the code and it seemed to work with the only different placing a closing div tag on a separate line where as it was on the same line previously. Very odd. Unless I have over looked something - Maybe just a temperamental browser?

Comment: @DanielShillcock: This solution places the `xsl:apply-templates` inside the wrapper `div`. In your provided code it is *outside*.